# Is there a way to choose the sorting implementation I want in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for a way to sort a String, but I would like to be able to choose the implementation of the sorting algorithm, based on the requirements of the problem I'm modeling. Is there a builtin way to do that?

I understand that Python implements sort using Timsort, but such method is not in-place. I wonder if there is a simple way to just use Quicksort instead of having to write it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code) site has a category about [sorting algorithms](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms), most of which are implemented in multiple languages. All of the ones I've looked at have a Python implementation.

Among them, the quicksort page has a [python implementation](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort#Python).

Comment: The main reason that there isn't a (standard) library of sorting algorithms is that timsort [performs very well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Performance) on real-world data. Generally better than quicksort or merge sort.

Comment: Do you know if it is done in-place? I would choose Quicksort over Mergesort for that reason.

Comment: Usually no algorithm is perfect and there are tradeoffs, that's why I don't understand why there is no builtin way to choose the implementation that I want...

Comment: Given the way Python works (variables being references to objects), I'm not sure if the term "sorting in-place" has any meaning. As for the reason why there isn't a way to choose sorting implementations, let me quote from the Zen of Python "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."

Comment: I believe that term 'in-place' makes sense if we are talking about the Python internals, as it's written in C. I was taking a closer look at the documentation and it turns out that `[].sort()` is in-place, as I needed. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html

Answer (score -2):

`''.join(sorted(str))` will return a sorted string.
You can google stuff-

https://github.com/href/Python-Unicode-Collation-Algorithm

http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/

edit- Why the -1? Lol.

Comment: Ahh ok , good lol.. thanks. Will edit it out.